# Javascript form validation - PHP variable as VALUE - Invalid Input

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have an issue where I am validating form submission with javascript.  The form is prefilled with results from the database as PHP values like this:

```
<form name="profiledit" action="profile_edited.php" method="POST" >
     <h3>Name:</h3>
     <input type="text" id="teamname" name="teamname" 
          value="<?php echo $result['teamname'];?>">
</form>
```

This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function empty() {
   tn = document.getElementById("teamname").value;
   if (! /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(tn)) {
      alert("Please enter a valid Team Name");
      return false;
   }
}
</script>
```

The submit button is :

```
onClick="return empty();"
```

The problem is that is always tells me top "Please enter a valid Team Name" unless I retype the text in the box (that was supplied by the PHP value).

I cannot see any weird spaces or things in "view source".

What could the problem be?

Thanks.

EDIT1 : Sorry I forgot to paste closing brace.  It was there in the code and this does work for BLANK forms OK.  Just not when it has a prefilled value from PHP.

Comment: Any console error message in browser?

Comment: Maybe there's a space at the beginning or end of the initial value?

Comment: You don't have an equal number of open and close braces {, }.

Comment: try trimming the value before processing something like document.getElementById("teamname").value.trim();

Comment: Yes you don't have proper opening and closing braces. and try to trim your value before pattern matching.

Comment: you can trim with php aswell <?php echo trim($result['teamname']); ?>

Comment: Sorry the lack of Brace was my paste fault.  They are there and it does work for blank form submission but not for "prefilled" edit form submission.

Comment: I just tried the trim but that is same results.  There are no funky chars in the variable.  It is like there is no data there and if I put in one char then it is fine, it is like the php variable is a ghost :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

[Check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/e8y772oL/1/)

**Html**

```
<form name="profiledit" action="" method="POST"  id="profiledit">
     <h3>Name:</h3>
    <input type="text" id="teamname" name="teamname" value=""/>
         <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
<input type="submit" id="submitform" value="submitform" name="submit" style="display:none;" /> 

</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#submit').click(function(){

   var pattern=/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
   var  tn = $("#teamname").val();

    if(tn == ""  && pattern.test(tn)){
     alert('1');   
    }else {
     //alert('2');   
        $('#submitform').trigger('click');
    }


});
```

Hope its helps

Comment: I assume you missed the brace there? in the if.  I tried it anyway and it does not validation at all and goes straight to submit.

Comment: check the updated link and code sure its helps for u

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I dont have a value using this.  I use PHP echo to fill in the VALUE (so users dont have to retype it all).  There is more than one check in the validate.  Good go though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there was nothing wrong with the responses after all.  My code was good and you guys code was good as well.
The problem?

Well I just happened to be testing with a teamname that had a SPACE in it!!!!!!!!!!

So having finally worked out that was the problem all along I would like to thank you all for your inputs.

I have used the regex instead : /^\w+( \w+)*$/

Allows words, numbers and a space.